# Updating SDK 2.3 - what exactly are the SDK Platform tools?

Tags: android

I wish to update my SDK 2.3 to the latest revision of 2.3. I don't want to update to 3.0 preview and lose the GPS emulation and have a slow emulator. 2.3 is just fine for me. I've updated the ADT plugin to 9.0.0 by the Eclipse 'check for updates'.

If I run the AVD manager from Eclipse and look at my installed packages, I have installed :
[image]

and the available packages with the ones that I ***think*** I want checked are:
[image]

My question is: what do I get with the platform tools? Is it just what goes in the platform-tools folder (i.e. the aapt.exe, adb.exe etc)? I don't want to overwrite the tools folder and end up with the slow emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, platform-tools are adb.exe and friends.  You will also want Android SDK Tools, revision 9 as well, and don't worry about Honeycomb stuff - even if you do install them, they won't interfere with you (for example you can filter on platform version within the developer docs).

Comment: Won't the SDK Tools rev 9 come with  the emulator that's so slow? According to the release notes :"Known issues with emulator performance: Because the Android emulator must simulate the ARM instruction set architecture on your computer, emulator performance is slow. We're working hard to resolve the performance issues and it will improve in future releases."

Comment: Or is it just 3.0 AVDs that are slow in the emulator?

Comment: @NickT: The emulator is slow, period.  It's slow on my i7 at work and my i5 Macbook Pro.  I don't think there is any reason to believe that the revision 9 version is slower than previous versions.

Comment: Mine's not too bad on 2.3 on a Windows 2GHz box. I think in the next few days, I'll download all the latest 3.0 stuff to a new folder, make a copy of Eclipse, point it at the 3.0 SDK, install the latest plugins and see how it goes in the duplicate environment. The main sticking point for me is that the APKs made with 3.0 will only run on an emulator